# How MySQL connector jar version can affect query performance?

Tags: java, mysql, connector-j

Currently, in my application with mysql-connector-java:5.1.36, everything works fine. But when I upgrade connector to mysql-connector-java:5.1.47, a query starts to take minutes-2-hours time to execute. If I run the same query directly from the terminal or from the application with v5.1.36, it takes less than a few seconds to execute.

How MySQL connector jar version can affect query performance?

Comment: Query - https://pastebin.com/LvxHb8us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. There is a change in mysql-connector-java:5.1.47 and above:
When UTF-8 is used for characterEncoding in the connection string, it maps to the MySQL character set name utf8mb4. While for mysql-connector-java:5.1.46 and below it corresponds to utf8 (or utf8mb3 more appropriately).

Link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

For my database character encoding is set to utf8 (or utf8mb3 more appropriately). Due to this index was not being used in query. After setting server property

```
character_set_server : utf8
```

it is working fine.